# Why is my .done triggering before the promise is complete?

Tags: promise

I'm trying to get my head around promises and I've had a few successes, but I've now got one that's triggering before the promise is finished processing. Clearly I'm misunderstanding what the trigger is, and would appreciate any assistance to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
function editPer () {
    // load permissions from server
    $.when(loadPermissions())
    .done( function () {
        // display returned data
        console.log('done');
        console.log(permissions);
    })
    .fail(console.log('fail'));
} // end function editPer

function loadPermissions () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "server/permissions.php",
        data: {action:'list',acc:33},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            listPermissions(data);
        } // end success function
    }); // end ajax
} // end function loadPermissions

function listPermissions (data) {
    status = data.status;
    if (status == 'LISTREADY') // list successful
    {
        // create list
        permissions = data.list; 
    }
} // end function listPermissions
```

`loadPermissions` runs successfully and passes the data to `listPermissions`, which creates the list (with one entry). My `editPer` function shouldn't process until the list is ready, but when I try to output the list it's empty.

To further confuse me, both `.done` and `.fail` are triggering in `editPer` indicating the deferred has been both resolved and rejected.

How can I ensure `.done` only triggers when the list is ready (`listPermissions` has run to completion)?

`listPermissions` can be called from other functions so I'd rather keep `listPermissions` and `editPer` separate. And if there's a better way of doing this without a promise, I'm interested in learning that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument(s) to `when` should be deferred(s), but actually you pass `undefined` instead, because the function `loadPermissions` does not return anything.

The deferred to return is the one that the call to `$.ajax` returns, so ... return it:

```
return $.ajax({ // ...
```

Secondly, your `fail` handler is not a function, since you execute `console.log` immediately. It should be:

```
.fail(function () {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

I should mention that the use of global variables (`permissions`) is not the best practice. You may want to let your deferred resolve to those values, instead of having them as globals.

Here is how it could look:

```
function editPer () {
    loadPermissions().then(function (permissions) {
        console.log('then');
        console.log(permissions);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('catch: ' + error);
    });
}

function loadPermissions () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "server/permissions.php",
        data: {action:'list',acc:33},
        dataType: 'json',
    }).then(function(data){
        return listPermissions(data);
    });
}

function listPermissions (data) {
    // Throwing error will make the promise reject and execute the catch callback
    if (data.status != 'LISTREADY') throw "not ready";
    return data.list; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @trincot. This sounds promising, but:
- the return from $.ajax isn't sufficient. I want the permissions variable that has been created from the results of $.ajax.

Comment: That is not what you asked in the question. But I agree that you should return it (see my final paragraph). Have you tried returning it? In your question's code you don't do it...

Comment: I tried adding 'return (permissions)' before I posted my comment (after reading your final paragraph), but it didn't change anything. I'm sure that I'm missing how to make my loadPermissions a deferred, which is why it's resolving immediately. Or is the problem that loadPermissions is counted as completed even if listPermissions hasn't been run?

Comment: To make `loadPermissions` return a deferred, you should `return $.ajax(...`, if you don't, it resolves immediately (because `undefined` is not a promise).

Comment: Also take care that code that follows the call to `editPer` will also execute before the response, so it should not rely on it. Any code dependent on the response should be in an asynchronous callback function.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works (after replacing '==' with '!='. I'll mark it solved

Comment: I'm still playing with your code to make it do exactly what I want, and to absorb your more recent comments, but you've definitely pointed me in the right direction.